# How to change k8s's pods limts without killing the original pod?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Requst:limits of a pod may be set to low at the beginning, to make full use of node's resource, we need to set the limits higher. However, when the resource of node is not enough, to make the node's still work well, we need to set the limits lower. It is better not to kill the pod, because it may influence the cluster.

Background:I am currently a beginner in k8s and docker, my mentor give me this requests. Can this requests fullfill normaly? Or is it better way to solve this kind of problem? Thanks for your helps!
All I tried:I am trying to do by editing the Cgroups, but I can only do this in a container, so may be container should be use in privileged mode.

I expect a resonable plan for this requests.
Thanks...

Comment: Recreating pods is pretty normal.  Usually making this sort of change you'd change the deployment, and let it create a new pod and destroy the old one.

Comment: You are approaching k8s the wrong way, imho. At its very core, it is an orchestrator of runtimes, network layers, storage and last but not least, computing. Let k8s do its job and do not try to fine tune stuff like that. You should rather see `requests` as k8sese for „Hey, this pod absolutely needs this to run“ and `limits` as „if we hit this limit, TSHTF and you should not allow more“. If you need to do Ressource management manually, your cluster is VERY likely too small for your workloads. Remember, when a node fails, the others need to be able to run the loads of the failed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is you want to change limits **without killing the pod**.

This is not the way Kubernetes works, as [Markus W Mahlberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg) explained in his comment above. In Kubernetes there is no "hot plug CPU/memory" or "live migration" facilities the convenient hypervisors provide. Kubernetes treats pods as ephemeral instances and does not take care about keeping them running. Whether you need to change resource limits for the application, change the app  configuration, install app updates or repair misbehaving application, the **"kill-and-recreate"** approach is applied to pods.

Unfortunately, the solutions suggested here will not work for you:

- Increasing limits for the running container within the pod ( `docker update` command ) will lead to breaching the pod limits and killing the pod by Kubernetes.
- Vertical Pod Autoscaler is part of Kubernetes project and relies on the "kill-and-recreate" approach as well.

If you really need to keep the containers running and managing allocated resource limits for them "on-the-fly", perhaps Kubernetes is not suitable solution in this particular case. Probably you should consider using pure Docker or a VM-based solution.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this default "kill and recreate" behaviour of Kubernetes after performing "docker update" command? I know this is not a correct way of working with Kubernetes but I'm asking this for a research project. In this project, killing and recreating pods is a very timely expensive task as we need to do it several times...

Comment: No. "If a Container exceeds its memory limit, it might be terminated. If it is restartable, the kubelet will restart it, as with any other type of runtime failure. If a Container exceeds its memory request, it is likely that its Pod will be evicted whenever the node runs out of memory". "Evicted" means "kill on this host and recreate on another host". Kubernetes is not aware about other techniques by design. I am quoting from here [How Pods with resource limits are run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run)

Comment: hmmm...maybe for my particular case I can find a way to “disable” the k8s kubelet, does the docker update, perform my task (its a benchmark), enable kubelet again. I don’t care if it kills it after that...any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I do no think this is possible, there is an old issue tracking such thing on the kubernetes github (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9043) from 2015 and it is open.

Also, you should not rely on pod not being recreated while using kubernetes. Applications should be able to stateless to a point where if it dies in mid of a process, it could handle this failure and start it from the begin once it is started again.

I understand the idea behind trying to optimize the resource usage to it maximum but you should be also worried about a reliable process.

I think you should check out the Kubernetes' Vertical Pod Autoscaler, as it automates the resources of a pod depending on its usage. Maybe that could be an alternative: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the container ID's those running inside the pods and run this below command to increase the resources.

```
docker update --cpu-shares NewValue -m NewValue DockerContainerID
```

Comment: Kubernetes deprecated Dockershim, so is this still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

This now is possible as of April 11th, 2023 in Kubernetes version 1.27 with the alpha flag `InPlacePodVerticalScaling`

For details, there is a good blog with a video [here](https://kubescaler.io/blog/podresize/).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there is a resize option that has been made available..   however i think the approach may be wrong.  If you are using statefuleset then changes will spin a new instance with the  new changes before the old one is taken down.  If your applications are using services  the service will insure the application is available at all times by loadballancing the pods as they transition.

you can change the resources using a patch example:

```
kubectl -n qos-example patch pod qos-demo-5 --patch '{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"qos-demo-ctr-5", "resources":{"requests":{"cpu":"800m"}, "limits":{"cpu":"800m"}}}]}}'
```

Also with the latest kubernetes swapness is allowed.  I suppose a pod reaching its limit will not be killed if a pod has swap space.